# How to change Excerpt More on all posts on a page Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've added the following to my functions document to change the [...] to "read more" on all my posts pages, but it only effects the first post on the page.

```
    // Changing excerpt more
    function new_excerpt_more($more) {
        global $post;
        remove_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more'); 
        return '... <p class="moreinfo"><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . 'READ MORE' . '</a></p>';
    }
    add_filter('excerpt_more','new_excerpt_more');
```

Currently that code is at the bottom of my functions document, but I've had it elsewhere with the same result.
How do I get this to apply to the excerpt of all posts?

Site is [http://shanepeacock.ca](http://shanepeacock.ca/books/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only need this:

```
function custom_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return sprintf( '<p class="moreinfo"><a href="%1$s" class="more-link">READ MORE</a></p>',
          esc_url( get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) )
    );
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'custom_excerpt_more' );
```